# C - Ncurses - How to stop cursor from moving over walls (walls made up of a bunch of charecters)

Tags: c, ncurses

Is there a way or function available which would stop me from going over the characters. The maze looks like the following below. I actually dont use printf, but mvprint. I just used printf as an example below.

```
printf("xxxxxx x");
printf("xxxxxx x");
printf("xxxxxx x");
printf("x      x");
printf("x xxxxxx");
printf("x xxxxxx");
```

I tried the this code below but it doesn't seem to work. The cursor still goes over the x characters. In the third line of the code you can see I've said that if there is a character 'f' there which is created by the bunch of `printf` statements seen above, the cursor shouldn't move. This doesn't seem to work.

```
if(m == 's')
{
    if((oldy+1,x)=='x') // This is the part of the code where i say that if the next spot is an 'x' dont move.
    {
        mvprint(win, 10,0,"Sorry, you cant move there.");   
        refresh(win);
    }
    else
    {
        move((y= oldy+1),x);
        refresh();
        oldy = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(oldy+1,x)=='x')` Isn't this line missing a `(`?

Comment: Yea, I fixed it, it was just a typing error on the site. It had no affect when the code though.

Comment: That's why I put it as a comment and not an answer ;)

Comment: Ty :). And.. How is this question flagged as a duplicate? Its asking totally different things.

Comment: "if you use **printf** or any other non-curses method of putting text on the screen (including a system call to another program that uses curses) you will not be able to read the content of the screen." - Appears you may need to switch from `printf`.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a duplicate either.

Comment: Does this mean no one else can see my questio now since its marked a sa duplicate? What should I do?

Comment: I'm guessing that `(oldy+1,x)` is the problem, since there's no function. You're just testing `x`, due to the comma operator, and `x` is very unlikely to be 120 ('x'). I forget the _what character is at this location_ function, though.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of research, I *think* you want your inner condition to be:

```
if(mvinch(oldy+1,x) == 'x')
```

The `mvinch(y,x)` function moves and returns the character at that location.

Also, as other people mentioned, mixing standard I/O and Curses is unreliable at best.  When I tried something like this on my machine to test, my program told me that the entire screen was made up of spaces.